# Create node link in views header and open in popup

Tags: views, javascript

Is there any option to include "Node Add" link in **Views header**, which to be opened in popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7) to create the 'add node' link.  As for the popup... perhaps you are speaking of the administrative overlay?  If that is the case and you have the overlay enabled, the 'add node' task should open in the overlay automatically.

You're probably looking for something like this (taken from [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1313132)):

```
function YOURMODULENAME_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  switch($root_path){
    case 'path_of_your_page' : // for example 'page/view/news'
      $item = menu_get_item('node/add');
      if ($item['access']) {
        $data['actions']['output'][] = array(
          '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
          '#link' => $item,
        );
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a normal `Global: Text area` header, using the *PHP code* text format, and in it put the following code:

```
<?php if (user_access('create article content')): ?>
<a href="<?=url('node/add/article')?>">Add new article</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

[Darvanen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131247/create-node-link-in-views-header-and-open-in-popup#answer-131273) is correct that the overlay will be used if you have that module enabled.